# How to swap / remap the Escape key with backtick (`) and Caps-lock with Escape Key

Tags: ubuntu, x11, gnome, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

So I just bought a 60% keyboard, and I didn't realize that the backtick doesn't have it's own dedicated key. This is problematic as I write a lot of Markdown and JavaScript.

It seems like swapping the **escape key** with the **caps-lock** key is pretty common, and gnome-tweaks even has a GUI to do this for you.

I haven't done this before, but it looks like `xmodmap` is the normal way to do this? If so I'm struggling to figure out **the keycode for the backtick**.

**Does anyone know the xmodmap keycode for the backtick symbol?**

Even better, an example of how to swap the escape key with the backtick & the capslock key with the escape symbol would be amazing.

(I know there's a number of similar questions, but they seem to focus on only caps lock swap with escape)

Thanks!

Comment: I've grown attached to https://github.com/houmain/keymapper -- remap my whole keyboard to swedish dvorak with layer keys for special characters. Simple and powerful, and suits well for minor changes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you're looking for is the keysym name for the grave accent symbol, as keycodes refer to the keys themselves and the name "backtick" is only really used for the symbol in programming. From my system's <X11/keysymdef.h> header file, where the `xmodmap` man file says the list of keysym names may be found, the keysym name for the grave accent is `XK_grave`. According to the man file, the keysym could also be specified using the grave accent's Unicode value as "U0060".

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `xev` what key codes map to what keys.

I then generated a added `clear lock` to the top, so that caps_lock can be remapped. I then set `keycode   9 = grave asciitilde grave asciitilde`  and `keycode  66 = Escape NoSymbol Escape`

This seems to make things work in VIM, and other linux applications. But does not seem to work in some applications. I'm starting to think anything outside of the firmware on the keyboard might be a waste of time.